# Does positive charge absorb electromagnetic radiations?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics

We know the electron that jumps from a higher energy to a lower energy state emits its energy in the form of electromagnetic radiation. What will happen if a proton jumps from a higher energy state to a lower energy state?

Comment: My mind went to excited nuclear states, although of course a lone proton isn't going to display those...